# Task Limit for Async Calls?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, task

I have a .NET 4.5 WCF client that works synchronously. I am updating it to use the new async/await functionality to make multiple simultaneous server calls to get chunks of data concurrently.

Before i finish, I have a concern that all of the threads running at the same time will saturate the server (not to mention kill my Azure worker role when I upgrade to that next year). Is there a way to centrally govern the total amount of Task threads I use at the class level? The code shares an assembly with other WCF client code.

Thanks for all ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question literally: you can control the number of threads used to handle Tasks by implementing your own [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321418.aspx) and assigning it to every Task you create. Microsoft even has a [fully working example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx).

To answer the underlying issue, though: `Task` does not imply `Thread`. In fact, the primary goal of async/await is to *reduce* the number of threads in your app. It's actually possible to have an entire app designed around async/await and Tasks, with thousands of concurrent tasks running, which uses only a *single* thread.

You want your code running in as few threads as possible, ideally no more than the number of logical CPUs you have, and you want the I/O to happen concurrently with your code. The OS can manage all that I/O for you without creating additional threads. Tasks help you accomplish this.

The only time it could create a thread-per-task is if you're emulating asynchronicity, eg. calling Task.Run to run blocking code. This kind of code is indeed unwise:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(()=>DownloadFile(url1));
Task t2 = Task.Run(()=>DownloadFile(url2));

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2)
```

Truely asynchronous code (which could run in a single thread) is far better, eg:

```
Task t1 = DownloadFileAsync(url1);
Task t2 = DownloadFileAsync(url2);

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2)
```

or, for an arbitrary number of tasks:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(string url in urls)
{
    tasks.Add(DownloadFileAsync(url))
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me something to think about/through. Follow-up, I do not know how many Tasks I need to spin up, I am using foreach() to execute a WCF call multiple times. How to adapt your "Truely asynchronous code" example to use foreach?

Comment: Example added. One thing, though: I don't think web service proxy classes allow concurrency, so you may have to open a new instance for each call. Underneath the hood, though, service proxy classes do tend to pipeline these so you may end up still only using one connection.

Comment: More thanks. I was messing with my own idea (creating instances with Lambdas), but your code is concise and has the advantage of actually working. I am testing to verify how much outbound thruput I can get from WCF but I do suspect I will hit an OS or hardware limit, which is fine because that can be addressed later. I just need the tightest code possible where I can control it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of asynchronous WCF servers, there are no "Task threads".

You have `Task` instances that represent in-progress requests, but they are not thread pool threads. The server will allocate thread pools as needed to requests that have some work to do; a request that is asynchronously waiting (in an `await`) does not have a thread.

Comment: Are you saying that if I split my List<Task> into 4 List<Task> and fill them with equal stuff and then await on each one, I will use 4 threads?

Comment: No. I'm saying that you don't use any threads in an `await` unless you have explicitly started work on the thread pool (e.g., `Task.Run` or `TaskFactory.StartNew`).