# C# limit number of async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, httpwebrequest, limit

So I have this code:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxsize).Select(index => CallRequestsAsync(param1[index], param2[index]));
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

This code calls a bunch of async tasks that are doing webrequests and other work. I want to limit the number of maximum active running tasks at a time,lets say 50 at a time.Then,if one finishes work,a new one will be called,so basicly there will always be 50 running async tasks at a time until it finishes my list. So how can I accomplish that by using the format above? The index is an int,used to retrieve paramaters from external variables.

Comment: Well, thats nice but where is the question?

Comment: Since this question asked many times already (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574377/task-limit-for-async-calls) could you please clarify why existing solutions you've already tried did not work for you? (Note that by deciding not to show what you've already tried you are welcoming downvotes on the post)

Comment: Note that `async`/`await` doesn't launch multiple threads.

Comment: My problem is that when using the code above,all the requests are launched almost instantly and is heavy on the CPU,I want to set a limit of how many async tasks are running at a time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task Limit for Async Calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574377/task-limit-for-async-calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing something similar to below:

```
        var maxsize = 50;
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int index = 0; index < int.MaxValue; index++)
        {
            tasks.Add(CallRequestsAsync(param1[index], param2[index]));
            if (tasks.Count > maxsize)
                Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
        }
```

Comment: This method wont launch adittional tasks,this waits untill all 50 are finished.Is there a way to accomplish what I said above?

Comment: I see what you mean. Please try the updated code above. I have updated my code to continue adding to the queue when any tasks has completed.